# Heroku ignoring changes from GitHub?

Tags: git, heroku, github

Heroku seems particular about what it decides to deploy from GitHub.  I'm working with Django, if it matters.

So I've setup a Heroku pipeline for deployment, including the app `myapp-staging`.  It's connected to my GitHub app `myapp`, pulling from the `staging` branch.  So upon commits to GitHub in this `staging` branch, Heroku should automatically pull and deploy all chages to `myapp-staging`.

I setup the whole thing, and it worked.  Automatic pushes to `myapp-staging` were working fine... for a while at least.

So I made a change to a file, `myapp/settings/base.py`, and committed it to my GitHub repository in `staging`.  The Heroku pipeline correctly noticed the change, and says it has automatically deployed the change.  But the app is broken.

I double checked:

- The app works fine on my local machine.  `git status` says everything is up to date, and on the correct `staging` branch
- `cat myapp/settings/base.py` shows the latest changes
- My changes are in the correct GitHub `staging` branch
- Automatic deploys from `staging` are enabled in Heroku.  Green checkmarks everywhere
- Heroku says everything is up to date, and that my build succeeded.  I looked in the deploy `diff`, which takes me to GitHub, where I can see my changes right on that screen
- I don't see anything problematic in `.gitignore`

However:

- `heroku run cat myapp/settings/base.py` does **not** show the latest changes
- App is busted.

It's like Heroku *says* it got the commit from GitHub, but isn't actually *using* it.  What gives?

I'm just getting started with Heroku, so I'm on the free tier, which apparently doesn't give me much access to logs or anything.  Hard to justify upgrading, though, if I can't get the app to work.

I tried `heroku restart`, and selecting `restart all dynos` from within the Heroku GUI; it didn't do anything.

Any ideas?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was running `heroku run cat myapp/settings/base.py` against the production (`master`) version of my app, which is apparently the default for Heroku.

Instead, I had to run `heroku run cat myapp/settings/base.py -a my-staging-app` to instead interface with my Heroku `staging` application, and to see the changes from GitHub.

All better now.  Hope this helps somebody in the future.